# Odd behaviour of sed to change specific string

Tags: bash, sed

I have launched this little script in bash:

```
for i in {001..020..1}; do
  sed -i "s/mbr001/mbr${i}/" ./mbr${i}/program_1.py
  sed -i "s/mbr001/mbr${i}/" ./mbr${i}/program_2.py
done
```

but I have noticed that, many times, the string mbr001 remained in some of the programas `program_1.py, program_2.py`. After launching the script many times, it seems now that *all* the appearances of `mbr001` have been changed to its correspondent string.

I have the suspicion that this behaviour is due to the fact that `sed` stops searching once it finds the specific string in a line and then jumps to the next, without considering other appearances in the same line.

Could you confirm this? How can one be sure that `sed` changes everything at once? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could you confirm this?

Confirmed

> How can one be sure that sed changes everything at once?

Add `/g` to replace all occurrences in each line rather than just the first one